# Is "set" countable or not?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, countability

This question comes from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3282322/673047).

> This figure is trying to illustrate 4 spaces defined by 4 different
>   set of standard basis.

In mathematics, the [standard basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis) (also called natural basis) for a Euclidean space is the **`set`** of unit vectors pointing in the direction of the axes of a Cartesian coordinate system.

if "set" is countable, the OP description would be 4 different sets of standard basis, so, is "set" here countable or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be "sets", plural.

> This figure is trying to illustrate 4 spaces defined by 4 different **sets** of standard basis.

A [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) shows intersection and union of **sets**, for example.

Sets are indeed [countable](https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/media/images/62558000/jpg/_62558092_15.thecountand8-richardtermine.jpg).